# I am using magento 2.2.3 with custom theme i wanted to add payment using composer when try to install its showing magento/framework not found

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, payment, composer

Do I Have Install Framework?
I Have Installed Magento using Installtron

Comment: Magento gives it's Framework content by default you can check at `Magento_root/vendor/magento/Framework` you don't need to install it separately please check the **`exception.log`** or **`system.log`** file located at `Magento_root/var/log` to find the error properly.

Comment: Thanks For your reply system.log is not opening and exeption.log is showing this Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'lakdi-ghana-oils.html-1' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID' at /home/cqczf22myicd/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []

Comment: #34 /home/cqczf22myicd/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#35 {main} [] []
[2018-04-30 11:58:47] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/petmark/petmark_default/en_GB/css/images/grabbing.png' [] []
[2018-04-30 15:20:53] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/petmark/petmark2/en_US/requirejs-config.js' [] []